# Using Ajax to dynamically insert images for the owl carousel

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, owl-carousel

I am trying to insert images from a json file using Ajax. These images will then be used by the owl carousel, however currently it is only displaying the last image in json file.

Here is my code:

html

```
     <div class="content newFilms">
        <h2 class="welcomeText">New Releases</h2>
        <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme"></div>
    </div>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.getJSON("data/owl.json",function(img){
       $.each(img, function(index,img){
            var $newImg = $(img.item);

        $(".owl-carousel").append($newImg);

       });
  $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
      dots:true
  });

});
});
```

json

```
[
{
    "item":"<img src='images/slide1.jpg'/>",
    "item":"<img src='images/slide2.jpg'/>",
    "item":"<img src='images/slide3.jpg'/>"
}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have multiple identical keys in the same object.

I suggest a different data structure. A top-level object that has an `images` property, which is an array of objects, each carrying information about a single image.

```
{
    "images": [
        {"url": "images/slide1.jpg"},
        {"url": "images/slide2.jpg"},
        {"url": "images/slide3.jpg"}
    ]
}
```

Then the code follows naturally:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("data/owl.json").done(function (data) {
        $.each(data.images, function(index, img) {
            $('<img>', { src: img.url }).appendTo(".owl-carousel");
        });

        $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
            dots:true
        });
    });
});
```

Note that it's not a good idea to have the finished HTML inside your JSON, as this limits what you can do with it on the client side and leads to useless duplication in the JSON data.

jQuery makes it quite easy to build HTML elements from data, make use of that feature and only include the actual *data* in the JSON. The client-side code can take care of the details how to render it.

Comment: Thanks, although this isn't working for me. It isn't loading any of the images.

Comment: Have you changed the JSON file?

Comment: I had, I just noticed that last item had a comma at the end, my bad. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Oh, yeah, I've seen that too late in my answer as well. Always check the browser console for errors, these things will typically show up there.